# Facebook Graph API Image get URL Signature Expired

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I use facebook API to Login in my project. But for long time, all user image in my project is broken image and get `URL signature expired`. Even though, I grab URL picture same in website facebook developer. And this is my code :

```
var profile_picture = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture";
```

Any solution for me ? because I really confused right now. Thank you very much.

Comment: This URL redirects to the current profile picture of the user on the Facebook CDN. Did you store the final URL, after the redirect? Don’t do that; those are to be considered “transient”, and not meant for long-time use.

Comment: Then what should I use ?

Comment: Well use the URL above when you need to show the user's profile picture.

Comment: I did. I used the URL above when I need user's profile picture but still not working.

Comment: How exactly is it “not working”?